# Is it possible to use Jsweet source code Version (2.0.0) to customize JavaScript file

Tags: java, maven, jsweet

I am using maven and pom.xml to generate javascript from java class. In pom.xml
jsweet's dependency,repository is available there. when i build the project i am finding javascript file.

- Now i need some modification during generation time of javascript file.
- So i was searching, and i found jsweet source code from this [link](https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet/releases) (Version 2.0.0).
- Can i use that project to replace maven and pom.xml
- If it is possible, i will try to change the code to get my required javascript file.
- I think make jar file of that jsweet source code project, and use in my project which i want to generate javascript file or code.

Please, some one try to understand the requirement, help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is it exactly you need to have changed?

Comment: I need some own customization of javascript file, because default dependency has no facility to modification. for